# How to clear just the data from multiple Excel spreadsheets after copying using VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I am brand new to VBA and I have some code to transfer data from multiple spreadsheets into one master spread sheet. This works ok but at the end I need to clear the days data from each of the spreadsheets so the data can be transferred again the next day with out duplicating. Is there something simple I can add to the end of my script to clear all the data I have just transferred? Any help would be very greatly appreciated

Here is my script so far:

```
Sub LoopThroughDirectory()

Dim MyFile As String
Dim erow
Dim Filepath As String

Filepath = "C:\Users\Guy\Desktop\nichola\"
MyFile = Dir(Filepath)
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0
    If MyFile = "ZMASTER.xlsm" Then
    Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
    Range("A2:E25").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 5))

    MyFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: If you need to delete the data from the source sheet why don't you use CUT instead of COPY?

Comment: I tried that and but it didn't work even when I save the changes in the individual workbooks the data is still there?

Comment: Have you tried `.clearcontents` on the same range just after paste? Do you have write permission in the workbooks?

Comment: I tried to clear contents after the paste. I repeated the range bit then clear contents but it wouldn't run.

Comment: I am brand new at this im afraid so even doing simple things are coursing me problems. I do have permission for all the workbooks.

Comment: And what is missing from your code: You need to save the workbook before closing it, otherwise deletion won't really happen.